# Send Text Msg to Mobile Number

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am working on some website in which I fetch some user information from DB to webpage and I also have one textbox and one send msg button on this page. I want that when user puts any mobile number on the textbox and click send button then the text message should go on that Mobile number with some data i want to send.

Mail functionality is very easy to implement but I never user text msg kind of functionality.
Tell me in detail which server or port I have to use it and I want to send free unlimited text msgs like we send mails from Google server.

How to do it?

Comment: Think you'll have trouble finding a free and unlimited service. You'll need to purchase a subscription from specific providers

Comment: In US you can send an e-mail as a text http://www.emailtextmessages.com/

Answer (score 2):

I doubt you will find anything completely free. Here are two services Ive personally used, I think AWS stuff is probably better but you will have to experiment:

[AWS Simple Message Services (SNS)](http://aws.amazon.com/sns/)
and
[Twilio](http://www.twilio.com/sms)

Comment: I found twilio is easy to implement but when i tried it gives error: The file 'C:\Users\demo\Documents\GitHub\twilio-csharp\src\Twilio.Api\Core.cs' does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a GSM Modem(USB GSM Modem). it has AT Commands and you can easily send SMS to mobile phones.

Comment: i dont want to attach any modem or mobile device...its a website anybody from anywhere can send sms